# Someone revenge voting me?

Tags: discussion

I have lately noticed that as soon as I ask a question or post an answer, someone almost always downvotes it, and then often no one else ever does again. Sometimes, the downvotes go away after sometime, maybe because someone upvotes me then. How do I determine what is really going on? Is anyone else experiencing this?

EDIT: Someone is even down voting my super old answers.

Comment: Your answers are a little vague and could do with more research.

Comment: @Burgi, can you point out a particular answer (so that I can improve it)

Comment: As I pointed out, yesterday, you were a victim of a serial downvoter.  However, had honestly, the votes I sort of agree with.  Your questions are not very good.  Before you ask, pretty all of them, are low quality IMO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really find any evidence of it from my mod tools - no one's used a substantial number of *their* votes on your posts, nor has any one user downvoted any of your questions to a substantial amount.

You *do* seem on the verge of a question ban, cause I could have *sworn* I had seen one last night and its not there.

So no, as far as I can tell, there's no revenge or 'obvious', targetted serial downvoting that seems apparent to me.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll try to ask more relevant questions in the future. I also got some rep just now with "serial voting was reversed", so I guess that could be it.